# Чудовищный оборот "оплатить за"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фигуры-речи

Как вы думаете, существуют ли какие-то методы борьбы или всё, поздно, он стал нормой?((((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Давайте соблюдать правила русской грамматики

Оплатить – переходный глагол с сильным управлением, требующим обязательного присутствия объекта в форме В.п.

ПЛАТИТЬ,  1.  что. Отдавать  ДЕНЬГИ  в возмещение  чего-н.  П.  за  покупку. П.  долги.  2.  перен.,  чем  за  что. Возмещать,  воздавать.  П.  услугой  за  услугу. П. злом за добро.  сов. ЗАПЛАТИТЬ (ТОЛЬКО к 1 знач.).

ОПЛАТИТЬ, сов., что. Внести плату за что-н.  О. работу, счет. О. расходы по командировке.  несов.  оплачивать.

ОПЛАТА (= плата)  1. см. оплатить.  2. Выплачиваемые  за  что-н. деньги, плата.

2) Комментарий

Итак, правильно: платить деньги (за товар), заплатить деньги (за товар), оплатить товар.

"Оплата за труд" - это плата за труд, здесь нет вопросов.

"Оплатить за последнюю неделю пребывания в номере" с пропущенным словом "счет" можно счесть за небрежность, разговорный стиль или что-нибудь еще, но фраза очень напрягает слух и кажется неграмотной.

3) Это и есть охлотизация языка

А когда она перестанет напрягать слух, то можно поздравить общество с очередным "достижением". Потому что охлотизация, которая здесь недавно обсуждалась, это не только "направленное снижение общей речевой грамотности в угоду повседневной мелкобуржуазной стихии". Стихия сама наступает. Кто сейчас будет задумываться о значениях приставок": О или ЗА - какая разница? Чувство языка теряется, растворяется в массе.

Comment: Здесь обычное развитие языка, ничего не попишешь. И падежи меняются, и предлоги. Так всегда было, есть и будет.

Comment: Переходность/ непереходность - фундаментальные понятия в грамматике, не стоит относиться к ним без должного внимания. А то будем развиваться, последовательно отменяя сначала сильную связь, потом управление вообще, потом и до отмены падежей дело дойдет.

Comment: Процессы в языке всегда противоречивы, они часто против нормоустроителей нагло прут. Живой язык, не мертвый! 
>Олег Павлов. Степная книга (1990-1998)  
И тут же произведен расчет ― **оплатили за гроб водкой**, деньги на которую были собраны солдатами сообща.

Comment: Если в русском языке падежи отомрут, тогда русский язык преобразуется из "синтетического" языка в "аналитический" язык.

Comment: http://vivovoco.ibmh.msk.su/VV/BOOKS/LANG/LANG_8.HTM
Корней Чуковский "ЖИВОЙ КАК ЖИЗНЬ" (Рассказы о русском языке). Нельзя говорить: оплатить за проезд, надо говорить: оплатить проезд.

Comment: Лично мною такие нововведения воспринимаются не как развитие, а как свитие языка. Сжимание, уплощение, перекорёживание.


При том, что я вовсе не граммар-наци. Спокойно отношусь к множеству заимствований, сленгу (где попадаются сочные словечки с чётко очерченным лексическим значением). 


Но здесь-то речь идёт не о лексике, которая может существенно меняться в течение жизни одного поколения, это ГРАММАТИКА! Структура, скелет языка! Святая святых!


Галактион совершенно прав: того гляди докатимся до состояния "аналитический язык"... пациент скорее мёртв, чем жив...

Comment: "Живой язык, не мёртвый!"

И живой организм, случается, причиняет себе вред. 


В конце концов, мы тоже носители языка и тоже можем "нагло переть". В противоположную сторону.

Comment: "Оплатить – переходный глагол с сильным управлением, требующим обязательного присутствия объекта в форме В.п."


И непременно без предлога.

Answer (score 3):

Есть выражение : *оплата за труд*.

> § 4. Часть 2 ст. 132 Кодекса закрепляет принцип **равной оплаты за равный труд.**
>
> А. И. Солженицын. Архипелаг ГУЛаг (1958-1973)
> Вероятно, устраивали товарищеский обмен опытом, «учились у передовых»; ну, и объявлялась «материальная заинтересованность» ― **повышенная оплата за ночные часы,** премиальные за сжатие сроков следствия;
>
> И. А. Ефремов. Лезвие бритвы (1959-1963)
> Ну что ж, это устраивает их и меня, плюс еще **порядочная оплата за затруднения.**

Оплатить за что :

> Владимир Орлов. Альтист Данилов (1980)
> Кровью и сединой **оплатить за великое сочинение**…
>
> В. В. Набоков. Защита Лужина (1929-1930)
> Как только его перевезли в больницу, она поехала в гостиницу за его вещами, и сначала ее не пускали в его номер, и пришлось долго объяснять, и вместе с довольно наглым отельным служащим звонить в санаторию, и потом **оплатить за последнюю неделю пребывания** Лужина в номере, и не хватило денег, и надо было объяснять, ...

*Оплатить за* - ничем не хуже *расплатиться за*. Только надо иметь в виду, что *оплатить за* - это сокращение более длинного выражения *оплатить СЧЕТ за*. Подставив слово *счет* в вышеприведенные цитаты из Орлова и Набокова, можно в этом убедиться.

Comment: Набоков это да, авторитет. Но режет же слух! Бррррррр!!!

А как Вам "помогите на"?

Answer (score 1):

Один из методов: тактично делать поправки. Многие просто не знают правил.

Comment: Да, если б это было искажение на уровне лексики... 

Как указать человеку на то, что он вообще плохо понимает, как устроен язык, который человек считает родным, и при этом не прослыть жутким занудой, не представляю...

Comment: Конечно, это нелегко. Многие выражают недовольство. Но я все равно всегда поправляю)