# "Оплата проведенных часов" или "оплата за проведенные часы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

**Оплата проведенных часов** или **оплата за проведенные часы**?
Какой вариант будет правильным?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36471/%d0%a7%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%89%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0

Comment: @Alex_ander. Tам в основном о глаголе *оплатить*, но попутно упоминается и *оплата за труд*.

Comment: Оплата - отглагольное существительное, образованное от сильно выраженного переходного глагола. Я считаю вариант "оплата за" просторечным, это чисто "кондукторское" выражение.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, оба варианта корректны, хотя есть еще вариант: "плата за проведенные часы".

Должен заметить, что вне контекста фраза о "проведенных часах", за которые полагается оплата, звучит несколько странно. Возможно, требуется уточнить, например: *за часы, проведенные у постели больного*.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)
ОПЛАТА, -ы; ж. 1. к Оплатить - оплачивать. О. труда рабочих. О. произведена не будет. О. квартиры, коммунальных услуг. 2. Уплачиваемые за что-л. деньги. Высокая, сдельная о.

[Управление в русском языке](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)
ОПЛАТА — 1. (в значении действия) чего. Оплата труда рабочих. 2. [уплачиваемые за что-л. деньги] за что. Высокая оплата за срочную работу.

Ответы Грамоты:

[291849](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=291849)
Корректно: плата за потребленный газ, оплата потребленного газа.

[286456](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286456)
Как правильно: оплата счета или оплата по счету? Спасибо.
Ответ справочной службы русского языка: Возможны оба варианта, выбор часто зависит от контекста.

[206573](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=206573)
Правильно: предварительная оплата (чего?) электроэнергии, предварительная плата за электроэнергию.

Но выражения *оплата чего-то* и *оплата за что-то* не всегда  взаимозаменяемы. Например:
*Оплата часов, проведенных внутри отсеков, производится помесячно.* (Тут нельзя сказать *оплата за часы*)
*Оплата за часы, проведенные внутри отсеков, составила 1000 рублей* (Тут нельзя сказать *оплата часов*)

Answer (score 1):

**оплата**
***чего*** и **за что**
1. чего (в значении действия). Оплата труда рабочих. Оплата расходов по командировке.

*Дополнительная **оплата часов, проведенных** внутри отсеков, баков и цистерн.*

2. за что (уплачиваемые за что-либо деньги). Высокая оплата за срочную работу. Сдельная оплата за труд.

*Дополнительная **оплата за часы, проведенные** внутри отсеков, баков и цистерн.*

[**Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь**](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/1465/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)

Приемлемы оба варианта, они взаимозаменяемы и имеют один и тот же смысл.

Comment: Не думаю, что они всегда взаимозаменяемы. Например: *Оплата часов, проведенных внутри отсеков, производится помесячно.*; *Оплата за часы, проведенные внутри отсеков, составила 1000 рублей*

Comment: А я и не говорила, _что они **всегда** взаимозаменяемы_. Я имела в виду только **своё** предложение.

Answer (score 1):

Отглагольное существительное **О**ПЛАТА образовано от сильно выраженного переходного глагола **О**ПЛАТИТЬ, **не** употребляемого без прямого дополнения, и требует употребления *в явном виде*  "**чего**" оплата.

> **Плата за часы** (или **о**плата **труда** за часы), проведенные там-то, так-то, тогда-то.
>
> **Оплата часов** (работы), проведённых там-то тогда-то.

Аналогично:

> **За**работная плата = плата **за** работу (но **о**плата **труда**, от "**о**плачивать труд").
>
> Ему **платят** (деньги) **за работу** -> ему **о**плачивают **работу**.
>
> **Плата за** проезд -> **о**плата **проезда**.

Comment: Сложно поверить, что в советские времена в солидных изданиях допускали просторечия в таких количествах. Да ещё и в специальной литературе. "Оплата за простой", например.

Comment: В специально литературе как раз много жаргонизмов. "Оплата за простой" - конечно же, плохо. Там хоть об оплате труда пишут или о перечислении суммы?

Comment: Об оплате (не)труда :) Например: "трудовой кодекс, принятый в 1977 г., устанавливает оплату за простой в размере среднего заработка." Интересно найти в трудовом кодексе, там вряд ли будут жаргонизмы.

Comment: В трудовом кодексе встречается несколько раз. Например: "обеспечивать работникам равную оплату за труд равной ценности" (обязанность работодателя).

Comment: Пример написанной юристами статьи http://trudprava.ru/base/crisis/870 о простоях в работе, со ссылками на трудовое законодательство, в которой **не** наблюдается произвола с "оплатой за простой". Слово "оплата" в разных сочетаниях встречается **10 раз**, из них 8 раз с существительным в родительном падеже (2 - оплата периода простоя, 3 - оплата времени простоя, 1 - оплата сверхурочной работы, 1 - оплата простоя, 1 - неоплата покупателями продукции).

Comment: _Дважды_ употреблена конструкция с "за": оплата за период простоя (пропущено подразумеваемое слово "труда" - но "простить" можно: это далеко не "оплата за проезд") и оплата за время простоя (при этом "труда" опущено в предложении, где сначала упомянуто о "положениях об оплате труда"). Так что не всё безнадёжно предопределено устами кондукторов :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Надо запомнить такое правило, что после "**за**платить" всегда пишется "**за**", а потом уже данное слово, в отличие от "оплатить", где не пишется предлог возле:

   > **За**платить **за** проезд
   >
   > Оплатить этот же самый проезд

Посему с герундием (это существительное, имеющее признаки глагола: сравните "жизнь" и "проживание" (герундий)) "оплата" то же самое: не нужен предлог:

> Оплата проведённых часов.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **Оплата проведенных часов**

**1) Управление в русском** языке

ОПЛАТИТЬ **что** **(не за что!).** Оплатить проезд в автобусе; Оплатить труд рабочих.

ЗАПЛАТИТЬ — 1. [отдать деньги **за** что-л.] за что. Заплатить за покупки; **Заплатить за проезд в автобусе**. 2. [возместить что-л.] что. Заплатить долги; Ростов, со времени своего проигрыша, решил, что он в пять лет заплатит этот долг родителям (Л. Т.).

ОПЛАТА, -ы; ж. 1. к Оплатить - оплачивать. О. труда рабочих. О. произведена не будет. О. квартиры, коммунальных услуг. 2. Уплачиваемые за что-л. деньги. Высокая, сдельная о.

**2) Из словаря грамматической сочетаемости  слов (РАН, 2013 год):** Правильно: **квартплата за квартиру и оплата коммунальных услуг.**

**Оплата за** — ошибочное сочетание, не различаются слова  ***плата и оплата.*** В словаре "оплата за" названа тавтологией.

Кажется, всё просто: **есть деньги, есть услуги, платим деньги за услуги или оплачиваем услуги**. Зачем ломать грамматику и **оплачивать за услуги**? Отсюда следует **плата за услуги и оплата услуг.** Но не всем хочется думать и говорить правильно, и не исключено, что нам придется слушать такую "нормированную" речь.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в ответе присутствует ошибка (или Ваша, или словаря). Я имею в виду "Правильно: квартплата за квартиру..."

Answer (score 0):

Как уже объяснили выше, допустимы оба варианта.

Приведу подробное объяснение из "Большого толкового словаря правильной русской речи" доктора филологических наук Льва Ивановича Скворцова.

[image: Оплата за]

Поскольку объяснение в словаре Скворцова вызвало неожиданные затруднения, процитирую ещё часть той же словарной статьи из того же словаря:

> В современной обиходно-разговорной речи встречаются неправильные
>   конструкции: оплата за труд; оплата за проезд; оплата за багаж и т.п.
>   Ошибка возникает под влиянием ложной аналогии с однокоренным словом
>   плата: плата за труд; плата за проезд; ...

Вот здесь как раз слово **оплата** обозначает действие по глаголу **оплатить**.

Comment: Скворцов Л. И. Большой толковый словарь правильной русской речи. — М.: Диля, 2006.   Лев Ива́нович Скворцо́в (1934— 2014).  Словарь Кузнецова (2014) ПЛАТА,  2. Денежное возмещение за пользование чем-л., за какие-л. услуги. Квартирная п. Повысить ПЛАТУ ЗА ПРОЕЗД.   Надо различать слова ПЛАТА  (ЗА) и ОПЛАТА. (ЧЕГО). Нормативность выражения ОПЛАТА ЗА  в словаре не зафиксирована. Если есть другие (более современные и авторитетные)  словари, дайте ссылку.

Comment: Я привёл цитату из словаря, в котором нормативность выражения ОПЛАТА ЗА не только зафиксирована, но и подробно объяснена с несколькими примерами. Почему я должен искать другие словари?

Comment: @Jasmin У меня издание 2009 г. У Вас есть основания считать этот словарь несовременным или неавторитетным?

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы это был официальный академический словарь 2014 - 2017 года.

Comment: Вы сравните эти словари. У них совершенно разное назначение. Словарь Скворцова имеет всего 8000 словарных статей и посвящён подробному разъяснению слов, которые вызывают трудности. Выше давали также ссылку на Розенталя. Вы считаете такое употребление устаревшим? Хорошо, тогда по Вашей логике в словаре Кузнецова 2000 г. издания должно быть зафиксировано ОПЛАТА ЗА. Предлагаю проверить.

Comment: Норма сочетания  неустоявшаяся. Мне лично "оплата за" кажется уступкой просторечию и поэтому раздражает.  В словаре 2014 года она не подтверждена, словарь сочетаемости издания РАН 2013 года называет ее ошибочной, поэтому вопрос остается открытым.